# Curlew reporting missing codecs

Tags: 18.04, codecs

Just did a fresh install of Bionic Beaver and used aptik to restore my PPAs and software from Xenial. When I try to convert an MP4 video to WebM using curlew I am seeing:
"libvorbis" audio codec not found
"libvpx" video codec not found

Using synaptic, I can see BOTH of those are installed on my system, so what am I missing?

Comment: Just upgraded a Xenial system where Curlew was working to Bionic, and now Curlew no longer works and is giving the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!  I had to delete the ".curlew" directory out of my home folder.  Apparently the settings from Xenial didn't carry forward properly to Bionic.  Deleting, and allowing curlew to rebuild it fixed the problem.